How to get transaction history with bought token amout in Solana blockchain?
Could someone please guide me on how to retrieve transaction history along with the bought token amounts on the Solana blockchain? Like it is in Dexscrener?
I want to get that information in Javascript but I do not know where to start, I see that helium does have transaction history api, but how should I proceed that it show like real-time or last transaction history of token and amount bought?
I do not need token holder wallets holding, just history with tokens bought:))
dexscreener
I did tried using helium, but it does only show me transaction history of wallets, but with GetProgramAccountsFilter i only can get those wallets holdings..
